# Gtkmm click signal for image widget

Tags: image, click, gtkmm

In Gtkmm how to respond to a click event on an image widget?I mean image widget does not support signal_clicked function like button widget .

Answer (score 2):

Put the image in an `EventBox` and connect to the signal on that.